# Quadratic programming with quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, constraints

I am trying to understand the proof given for a quadratic programming problem with quadratic constraints:

The optimization problem is:

[image]

where $\tilde{\beta}$ is $p \times 1$ and $X$ is $n \times p$. It states that if $\tilde{\beta}^\top \tilde{\beta} \leq c'$, $Tr(MM^\top)$ can reach its
unrestricted minimum $0$ at $\hat{M}$ = $\bf0$.

I don't understand how the constraint has become irrelevant if $\tilde{\beta}^\top \tilde{\beta} \leq c'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that the trace of such a matrix
$$
Tr(\mathbf{M} \mathbf{M}^T) = \sum_{r=1}^{p} \mathbf{m}_{r}^T \mathbf{m}_{r} \geq 0
$$
is nonnegative. As inserting $\hat{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{0}$ yields the trace
$$
Tr(\mathbf{0} \mathbf{0}^T) = \sum_{r=1}^p 0 = 0
$$
Using the first equation we know that there exists no matrix $\bar{M}$ such that 
$$
Tr(\bar{M}\bar{M}^T) < Tr(\hat{M} \hat{M}^T) = 0
$$
Therefore, if $\hat{M}$ is allowed by the constraint this must be a solution 
to the minimization problem. By inserting $\hat{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{0}$ into the constraint
$$
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\beta}^T(\hat{M} X - I_p)^T (\hat{M} X - I_p)\tilde{\beta} &\leq c' \\
\tilde{\beta}^T(\mathbf{0} X - I_p)^T(\mathbf{0} X - I_p)\tilde{\beta} &\leq c' \\
(-1)^2 \tilde{\beta}^T(I_p)^T(I_p)\tilde{\beta} &\leq c'
\end{align*}
$$ we see that $\hat{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{0}$ is allowed if
$\tilde{\beta}^T\tilde{\beta} \leq c'$.

PS: I apologize for not being consistent on the use of boldface.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Now I got it.